# How to change the database server in SharePoint server 2010?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, database, server-farm, topology

I have SharePoint Server 2010 installed on Server A (all the roles are on the same machine),and now 
I need to add a new server B which must be the new database server, so I need to move all the databases from 
server A to server B and point SharePoint server to the new database server.
In the end the server A will be web server and application server, and B will be the new database server. I followed the instructions in this [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx)
but nothing worked correctly - after I followed all the steps I opened the SharePoint central administration site only to receive an error "cannot connect 
to configuration database".

NOTES: port 1433 is opened on Server A and Server B, alias is working in SQL SERVER Management Studio.

Comment: I'm about to enter into something like this myself, if anyone has had any experience with this I'd be curious as to the results

Comment: Just found this similar question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2967/decommission-sharepoint-database-servers